# get the right position with PasteSpecial() in c++ using ole

Tags: c++, com, ms-office, c++builder, ole

I wrote a routine, that copies a word document and paste it in a new word document in c++ (Borland Builder 5)

```
tbSearch->Text = "{axis1[d]} ";
Variant vk_this_doc_select = wrdDoc1.OleFunction( "Select" );                // wir selektieren dessen Inhalt des geöffneten Dokuments
wordSelection = zuladendesDokument.OlePropertyGet("Selection");              // tun es in den ZwischenSpeicher der Applikation
wordSelection.OleFunction( "Copy" );                                        // und kopieren es
Variant vk_converted_document_select =  wrdDoc.OleFunction( "Select" );    // wir machen die Selektion im alten Dokument
Variant vk_converted_document_selection =   wrdApp.OlePropertyGet( "Selection" );
Variant  wordSelectionFind = vk_converted_document_selection.OlePropertyGet( "Find" );   // setzen den Zeiger
wordSelectionFind.OleFunction( "Execute", tbSearch->Text, false, false, false, false, false, true, 1, false, wordSelection, 2, false, false, false, false );
```

The routine works well, but in the insert routine the graphical parts of the word document is destroyed.

I tried also to insert the word document via

```
k_converted_document_selection.OleFunction( "PasteSpecial"), 0, false, 0, false, 0);
```

here the format is ok, but the position of the pasted document is wrong ( every times at the beginnig of the document.

So I have 2 questions:

- How to save the format?
- How to set the pasted word document to the right position?

After a while (and loosing 2- 10 nerve cells *fg*) I got the answer by my self, so I post the resultion for the next, dealing with this problem (sorry for my bad english). Hope anybody can use it...

```
           tbSearch->Text = "{axis3[d]}" ;

            Variant vk_this_doc_select = wrdDoc1.OleFunction( "Select" );// select the contain of the document to be insert

            wordSelection = zuladendesDokument.OlePropertyGet("Selection"); // select

            wordSelection.OleFunction( "Copy" ); // copy

            Variant vk_converted_document_select =  wrdDoc.OleFunction( "Select" ); // select the first document 

            Variant vk_converted_document_selection =   wrdApp.OlePropertyGet( "Selection" );

           Variant  wordSelectionFind = vk_converted_document_selection.OlePropertyGet( "Find" );   

                                                                                      // now the trick with is the solution: find the position you want, but do nothing ("")
           wordSelectionFind.OleFunction( "Execute", tbSearch->Text, false, false, false, false, false, true, 1, false, "", 1, true, true, true, true );

           vk_converted_document_selection.OleFunction( "PasteSpecial", 0, false, 0, false, 0); // now the pointer in the document is found, means PasteSpecial will insert the document at the right place
```